# Python Query From Teradata pyodbc Module

Tags: python, teradata, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=<DATABASE_NAME>;UID=<UID>;PWD=<UID>;QUIETMODE=YES;')
```

What actually goes in the Driver={} part?  Is this where I put the teradata `.jar` file such as `terajdbc4.jar`?

But this doesnt work, I get the error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'terajdbc4.jar' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two issues here:

1. As `fivetentaylor` mentioned, you're trying to use ODBC with a JDBC driver - and they don't work together. To use ODBC you need an ODBC driver - for Teradata on Linux I think [this](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/connectivity/odbc-driver/linux) is it.
2. You need to link the driver after you download it so that everything works.

To do so:

1. You need to put this driver in a directory where your linker will find it (you can use the `lld -v` bash command to find the folders where your linker scans for libs).
2. After you put this driver in the library, you typically need to configure the Driver in `/etc/odbcinst.ini` (look [here](http://www.unixodbc.org/odbcinst.html) for an explanation of the correct structure of the file.
3. Finally, you use the name of the driver you put in the odbcinst file in the last stage as the driver name. So for instance if you have a driver specified in the odbcinst.ini file like this:

   [Teradata]

   Description=Teradata driver

   Driver=/path/to/driver/file

You would use it like this:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME=<DATABASE_NAME>;UID=<UID>;PWD=<UID>;QUIETMODE=YES;')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try [jaydebeapi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/) if you want to use the jdbc drivers, pyodbc will only work with the traditional odbc drivers as far as i know.

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver',
                          ['jdbc:teradata://%s/database=%s' % (SERVER,DB), USER, PASS],
                          ['/path/to/tdgssconfig.jar', '/path/to/terajdbc4.jar'])
```

Comment: So what teradata driver do I need then to make this pyodbc.connect work?